# Using final methods to initialize an instance variable

Tags: java

From the [Sun docs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

> Normally, you would put code to
>   initialize an instance variable in a
>   constructor.
> There are two
>   alternatives to using a constructor to
>   initialize instance variables:
>   initialize blocks and final methods.

I could understand the use of initialize blocks. Can anyone please explain the use of final methods for instance var initialization? A non-final public setter can do this job. Why not just use them ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The advantage is already described in the very same Sun tutorial you linked to:

> **A final method cannot be overridden in a subclass.** This is discussed in the lesson on interfaces and inheritance.
>
> This is especially useful if subclasses might want to reuse the initialization method. The method is final because calling non-final methods during instance initialization can cause problems. Joshua Bloch describes this in more detail in [Effective Java(item 17 Design and document for inheritance)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).

The reason a non-final method is dangerous in initialization is because the instance initialization of the superclass executes before the sub class is initialized. Therefore if the non-final method is overriden in the sub class and is executed during the initialization of the superclass it may be accessing uninitialized fields of the subclass giving erroneous results.

The general rule is(quoting from Effective Java): **Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, directly or indirectly.**

Comment: @BalusC: Ya I read that but how would a child class overriding an initialization method affect parent class?

Comment: It would affect the behaviour definied by the parent class. This is simply not "Object Oriented" anymore. Either just don't extend the particular parent, or (re)define another instance variable.

Comment: @gameover: the problem is not the initialization method, it's the methods called in the initialization methods. If those methods are not finalized bad things can happen when a subclass redefines them.

Comment: I think it seems to be strange that base class initializer invokes the method defined in subclass(defined by overriding), not the original method defined in its own class.  Is it the same thing in C++?

Answer (score 4):

It's explained on the same page of the referenced tutorial. The reason is that a non-final method can be overriden by up subclass. Here's an example:

```
class Whatever {
    private List<String> myVar = initializeInstanceVariable();

    protected List<String> initializeInstanceVariable() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}

class Whoever extends Whatever {

    @Override
    protected List<String> initializeInstanceVariable() {
       return Collections.unmodifiableList(super.initializeInstanceVariable());
    }

}
```

So if you create Whoever, myVar will become unmodifiable ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### Other examples

#### From [alykhantejani.github.io](http://alykhantejani.github.io/initializing_instance_members_with_non_final/)

I made it compilable and simplified it.

**Duck.java**

```
public class Duck {

    String sound = "quack";
    protected String speech;

    public Duck() {
        initSpeech();
    }

    protected void initSpeech() {
        speech = "sound = " + sound;
    }

    public void speak() {
        System.out.println(speech);
    }

    protected String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }
}
```

**SqueakyDuck**

```
public class SqueakyDuck extends Duck {

    String squeakSound = "squeak";

    public SqueakyDuck() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void initSpeech() {
        speech = "sound = " + squeakSound;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getSound() {
        return squeakSound;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Duck squeaky = new SqueakyDuck();
        squeaky.speak();
        System.out.println(squeaky.getSound());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
sound = null
squeak
```

---

#### My example

**Superclass.java**

```
public class Superclass {

    protected int x = m();

    protected int m() {
        return 8;
    }

}
```

**Subclass.java**

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    private int y = 7;

    @Override
    protected int m() {
        return y;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Superclass s = new Subclass();
        System.out.println(s.x);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

**Order of execution:**

- `main`
- `m` from `Subclass` (`y` is **not initialized** in this moment and `0` is the default value for `int`)
- constructor `Superclass`
- constructor `Subclass`